# Function is repeating when I don't want it to

Tags: python, function, loops

The input function of my code is repeating 3 times before going onto the next function. I have tried using while true and break and return None but none of that helps.

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to the Interest Loan Calculator")

def inp():
    loan = input("Enter loan amount: ")
    rate = input("Enter interest rate: ")
    return loan, rate


def conv():
    loan, rate=inp()
    if loan.endswith('K'):
        multiplier = 1000
        loan = loan[0:len(loan)-1]
    elif loan.endswith('M'):
        multiplier = 1000000
        loan = loan[0:len(loan)-1] 
    return int(float(loan) * multiplier)

def calc():
    loan = conv()
    print (loan)

def close():
print ("close placeholder")

def  main():
    welcome()
    inp()
    conv()
    calc()
    close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running the code it asks me to input both loan and rate 3 times before moving to the calc function.

Comment: you call `inp()`, then you call `conv()` which in turn call `inp()` again, then you call `calc()` that in turn call `conv()` which in turn call `inp()` for third time

Comment: okay looks like i need to look up how to get my variables a different way. thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to call `inp` three times, then don't.  You call it once directly from the main program; you call it a second time through the sequence main => conv => inp, and a third time through main => calc => conv => inp.

I think you need to draw out the call tree of your program, and then alter it to match the design you actually want.

Comment: How would I pass variables from `inp` to `conv` without explicitly calling `inp`? I have looked this up and adding `loan, rate = inp()` under `inp` in my call tree just calls `inp` again.

Comment: Passing variables to and from functions is covered in any tutorial on the topic.  Asking here is off-topic.  Very simply, you call once, save the values, and pass those variables to any function that needs them.

Comment: Ok, looking at your tutorial. Thank you much and sorry for the off-topic comment.